# youtube quota limit per 100 seconds

Tags: youtube-api

I'm calling `youtube.liveChat` every 2 seconds but I often get the `403` errors.
I've checked that API console's allocation for the API that was "Queries per 100 seconds per user" is 300,000.

How can I allow to call the API every seconds?
Regards.

```
error:{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request was sent too soon after the previous one. This error occurs when API requests to retrieve messages are being sent more frequently than YouTube's refresh rates, which unnecessarily wastes bandwidth and quota.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request was sent too soon after the previous one. This error occurs when API requests to retrieve messages are being sent more frequently than YouTube's refresh rates, which unnecessarily wastes bandwidth and quota.",
        "domain": "youtube.liveChat",
        "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
      }
```

Comment: This is probably flood protection you need to slow down

Comment: Is 2 sec too fast?